# How do I merge text files in a particular order using cmd

Tags: cmd

I am using the following command `copy *.txt newfile.txt` to merge my text files into the main file but the order gets messed up. I have text files whose name are in the order

- 1january.txt
- 2february.txt
- 3february.txt
- 4march.txt
- 5may.txt
- 6june.txt
- 7july.txt
- 8august.txt
- 9september.txt
- 10october.txt
- 11november.txt
- 12december.txt

But using the cmd command it first appends 10october,11november,12december & then appends from 1january.

Is there any command in cmd that can do this or any other code will also do.

Comment: What about this: `copy 1january.txt + 2february.txt + ... + 12december.txt newfile.txt`? Naming them differently (like `01january.txt`, ..., `09september.txt`, for instance) can work, but you are likely still dependent on the file system then...

Comment: Cant do it as there are too many files

Comment: Well, I count 12 files... ;-)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in the question, but I have 100 years of data files and they have year too in front of them, for eg 1900_12december.

Comment: and there is always just one file per `YYYY_M*`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is this (given that the preceding numbers are positive and do not have leading zeros, and the file names do not contain `!` or `^`):

```cmd
cmd /V /Q /C copy nul "newfile.txt" ^& set /A "LIM=0" ^& (for %J in ("*.txt") do set "NUM=%~nJ" ^& set /A "NUM+=0" ^& set "$[!NUM!]=%~J" ^& if !LIM! lss !NUM! set /A "LIM=NUM") ^& (for /L %I in (1,1,!LIM!) do if defined $[%I] copy /B "newfile.txt" + "!$[%I]!" "newfile.txt")
```

If you place this code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) it might look like this (note that I additionally inserted several `rem` marks for explanation of the code here):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Enable delayed expansion to be able to write AND read variables in a single block:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Create empty target file:
copy nul "newfile.txt"
rem // Reset buffer for greatest preceding integer number:
set /A "LIM=0"
rem // walk through all matching files:
for %%J in ("*.txt") do (
    rem // Store base file name to variable, then covert it to integer:
    set "NUM=%%~nJ" & set /A "NUM+=0"
    rem // Write full file name to array-like variable with gathered integer as index:
    set "$[!NUM!]=%%~J"
    rem // Update buffer for greatest preceding integer number:
    if !LIM! lss !NUM! set /A "LIM=NUM"
)
rem // Count up from one to greatest preceding integer number:
for /L %%I in (1,1,!LIM!) do (
    rem // Check whether pseudo-array element is defined and append to target file then:
    if defined $[%%I] copy /B "newfile.txt" + "!$[%%I]!" "newfile.txt"
)
rem // End environment localisation:
endlocal
```